# How can I drag a drawn circle within a canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, dom-events, drag

I am coding up an assignment where I have to drag a circle drawn inside the canvas on top of an image of cheese and change another image of a mouse to mice celebrating. I've tried adding a `mousemove` event listener to detect the mouse pointer over the circle, and adding an `if` statement to see if the mouse pointer's X/Y values are greater than X/Y values.
I want to do this using `requestAnimationFrame`.

```
        canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", setMousePosition, false);
        function setMousePosition(e) 
        {
            mouseX = e.clientX - canvasPos.x;
            mouseY = e.clientY - canvasPos.y;
        }
        function update() 
        {
            context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
            drawText();
            loadCheese();
            loadMouse();
            drawLine();
            context.beginPath();
            var x = context.arc(mouseX,mouseY,40,0,2*Math.PI, true);
            context.fillStyle = "#FF6A6A";
            context.fill();
            context.stroke();

            requestAnimationFrame(update);

        }
```

This is my base code, which essentially makes the circle follow my cursor. The event handler corrects the mouse coordinates relative to my browser. `update()` draws all the necessary elements.

Comment: now you need an event handler. good answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28284754/dragging-shapes-using-mouse-after-creating-them-with-html5-canvas

Comment: Thanks. It did indeed have some great answers but how do I get it to detect if the circle is over an image, space, etc? Would that just be some `if currentXpos <>= x` while I'm dragging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm glad you found it useful.

this got a tiny bit too long for a comment so..

yes, utilize the matrix. it's not hard and makes sense if you look close enough :)

start with a square as other shapes require some extra math if you want it to be perfect. though extra math means less performance. thus a lot of game developers use square/cubed bounding boxes/hitboxes for collision detection.

oh and a small tip: keep away from decimals as floating points are more expensive. but JS rounding/Math methods can be worse so bit manipulation works great here(and other places too)

here's something for rounding:

```
// some quicker math
export const bitshift = {

   // this is for decimals only
   round_d: d => (d + (d > 0 ? 0.5 : -0.5)) << 0,

   // and with a multiple we round by the number we pass
   // to the second argument
   /** d: domain, m: multiple */
   round_m: (d, m = 1) => ((d / m + (d > 0 ? 0.5 : -0.5)) << 0) * m
}
```

basically bit shifting, if you're not familiar with it, is moving the 1s and 0s in one or the other direction in a Byte. by shifting left you get multiplication by 2 and division by 2 when shifting right, e.g:

```
0010 is 2
0100 is 4
0001 is 1
```

as you can imagine, doing actual math requires a lot more steps, and even if bit manipulation can be a little less accurate a few times because of how computers work. it's well worth knowing.

as for collission detection, here's a simple one for squares:

```
if (
   rx < x  + w && 
   rx + rw > x && 
   ry < y  + h && 
   rh + ry > y
)
   collided!
```

and for some heavy reading: http://www.jeffreythompson.org/collision-detection/matrix-transformations.php

best of luck and have fun! =)